# glade filechooserdialog Where does the opened file go?

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, glade

I learning how to use Python(2.7) GTK(2.0) and Glade(3.8) and at the moment i am trying to use the filechooserdialog to open a file and use it in my program, however i can not seem to find any information on where the opened file "goes". I have found many tutorials explaining how to use or make a file choosing dialog window but none explaning how to open the file in your program, for example i have a file with numbers that i want in a chart.
Does any of you kind gentlemen/women have a clue ?

Comment: GtkFileChoser doesn't give you file objects; it gives you filenames and URIs. You have to open the file yourself. How you open the file is up to you; Python has lots of different ways to deal with files, and GLib (which GTK+ uses) provides others. If you use the GLib-provided GIO interface that uses the GFile type, GtkFileChooser provides a method to get GFiles as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Indeed i did not understand how it worked, in the end i managed to open my file using the path that was given to me, and i felt dumb
Thanks again !

Comment: Don't feel dumb; it's all part of the learning process :)

Comment: You seem to be a kind person, thanks again for your help, have a nice day good sir(/lady) !